# How to check string contains special character in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to check whether a string contains special character in ruby. If I get regular expression also it is fine.

Please let me know

Comment: What characters do you consider 'special'?

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there) and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers

Comment: These are all special chracters ?<>',?[]}{=-)(*&^%$#`~{}

Comment: Did it work for you 
if it did then there is a tick check it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
special = "?<>',?[]}{=-)(*&^%$#`~{}"
regex = /[#{special.gsub(/./){|char| "\\#{char}"}}]/
```

You can then use the regex to test if a string contains the special character:

```
if some_string =~ regex
```

This looks a bit complicated: what's going on in this bit

```
special.gsub(/./){|char| "\\#{char}"}
```

is to turn this

```
"?<>',?[]}{=-)(*&^%$#`~{}"
```

into this:

```
"\\?\\<\\>\\'\\,\\?\\[\\]\\}\\{\\=\\-\\)\\(\\*\\&\\^\\%\\$\\#\\`\\~\\{\\}"
```

Which is every character in special, escaped with a `\` (which itself is escaped in the string, ie `\\` not `\`).  This is then used to build a regex like this:

```
/[<every character in special, escaped>]/
```

Answer (score 30):

Use `str.include?`.

Returns `true` if `str` contains the given string or character.

```
"hello".include? "lo"   #=> true
"hello".include? "ol"   #=> false
"hello".include? ?h     #=> true
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"foobar".include?('a')
# => true
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use inverse of `[:alnum:]` posix.

Here `[:alnum:]` includes all `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`.

Read more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Comment: "Hel@lo".index( /[^[:alnum:]]/ )


This will return nil in case you do not have any special character in your string and will return the index of your first special character otherwise

Answer (score 3):

```
"Hel@lo".index( /[^[:alnum:]]/ )
```

This will return `nil` in case you do not have any special character and hence eaiest way I think.

Answer (score 2):

How about this command in Ruby 2.0.0 and above?

```
def check_for_a_special_charachter(string)   
  /\W/ === string
end
```

Therefore, with:

```
!"He@llo"[/\W/].nil?  => True

!"Hello"[/\W/].nil?   => False
```

Answer (score -1):

if you looking for a particular character, you can make a range of characters that you want to include and check if what you consider to be a special character is not part of that arsenal

```
puts String([*"a".."z"].join).include? "a"    #true
puts String([*"a".."z"].join).include? "$"    #false
```

I think this is flexible because here you are not limited as to what should be excluded

```
puts String([*"a".."z",*0..9,' '].join).include? " "   #true
```