# Regex for only digits and special characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check that my string only contains numbers, spaces and the following special chars:

```
[ ] ,
```

I tried the following from "[How to check string contains special character in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343257/how-to-check-string-contains-special-character-in-ruby)":

```
special = "1234567890[], "
regex = /[#{special.gsub(/./){|char| "\\#{char}"}}]/ 
test1 = [1,2,[3,4],5].to_s
test2 = ["a",2,[3,4],5].to_s
```

When running these, they both return "fail":

```
puts "fail" if test1 =~ regex
puts "fail" if test2 =~ regex
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: `^` is the start of the string, `$` is the end of the string. A character class is defined with `[]`, inside you can put different characters. If these characters have special meaning, you can escape them so they will be matched literally with *back slash*. With `*` after the character class you can specify it to be repeated *0* or more times. Try it out.

Comment: You mean something like `/[^\d\s\[\]\,]/` which just says *Not a number,not a space,not [ (literally), not ] (literally) and not ,(comma)` if anything matches this then it includes something other than those characters. [Example](http://rubular.com/r/ZTyVJTHNTG). I feel like there might be more too this problem or a lack of understanding when it comes to regex. Please advise. Also note that `to_s` may add back slashes to escape strings even if that string is a number e.g. `["1","2","3"].to_s #=>  "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\"]"` (this will fail the regex due to the backslashes and the double quotes)

Comment: `/[^\d\s\[\]\,]/` wouldn't be correct. `\s` means more than a space, it's "white-space" AKA `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`. Also, it's not necessary to escape a comma in a set.

Comment: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) can be used for testing out Regex.

Answer (score 3):

Solution without regexp:

```
str = "123 [],"
# count all chars that are NOT 1-9, [] 
# the count should be zero
str.count("^0-9, []").zero? # => true
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. It'll run circles around any regex-based solution.

Comment: except an anchored one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
your_string.match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
```

I've tried this

```
2.2.2 :033 > "123a1231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
 => nil 
2.2.2 :034 > "1231231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
 => #<MatchData "1231231,2]" 1:"]"> 
2.2.2 :035 > "12.31231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
 => nil 
2.2.2 :036 > "aa1231231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
 => nil 
2.2.2 :037 > "12[31231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/)
 => #<MatchData "12[31231,2]" 1:"]"> 
2.2.2 :038 > "12[31231,2]".match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/).to_s
 => "12[31231,2]" 
2.2.2 :039 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
regex = /\A[\[\],\p{Zs}\p{N}]+\z/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/iiwagjSfEl) (note that `\A` and `\z` are replaced with `^` and `$` for demo purpose to match the whole line, not string).

Also, here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/hujLFW).

The regex matches:

- `\A` - Start of string
- `[\[\],\p{Zs}\p{N}]+` - 1 or more characters that are either `[` or `]` or a comma, or a space (`\p{Zs}`) or a digit (`\p{N}`).
- `\z` - end of string

**Why not `\A(\[|\]|,|\p{Zs}|\p{N})+\z`?** In case we use alternatives, the number of backtracking steps increases, and with very long string ends up in catatrophic backtracking quicker. In other words, it decreases performance.

**Why not `^`/`$`?** In Ruby, `^` matches at the beginning of a line, not the whole string. Same with `$`, it matches the end of the line, not the end of the string.

Comment: This results in `invalid character property name {Zs}: /\A[\[\],\p{Zs}\p{N}]+\z/`

Comment: Did you see [the demo](http://ideone.com/hujLFW)? It does not say that (Ruby 2.1).

Comment: Ruby complains about it. Whether the demo likes it or not doesn't help if Ruby won't compile it. I'll add yours into the benchmark but commented out. Try copying the benchmark and enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
special = "1234567890[], "
regex = /[#{special.gsub(/./){|char| "\\#{char}"}}]/
# => /[\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\0\[\]\,\ ]/
```

Use the tools available:

```
regex = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(special)) 
# => /1234567890\[\],\ /
```

[`Regexp.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) returns a properly escaped string:

```
Regexp.escape(special)
# => "1234567890\\[\\],\\ "
```

But wait, there's more:

Working with dynamically generated regex can have some gotchas that you need to be wary of, especially when you're trying to interpolate them into strings. Consider this:

```
regex = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(special)) # => /1234567890\[\],\ /
/^[#{regex}]+$/ # => /^[(?-mix:1234567890\[\],\ )]+$/
```

Notice the `(?-mix:` part? That's a regular expression's way of saying that "everything within `(...)` is using its own options for `m`, `i` and `x` so ignore whatever else the pattern tells it". That's a hole in your pattern that is *REALLY* hard to debug unless you're aware that it can exist. You need to read the Regexp documentation to understand what [the options](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) mean but here's an example of what craziness can happen:

```
(/^foo[#{regex}]+bar$/imx).to_s # => "(?mix:^foo[(?-mix:1234567890\\[\\],\\ )]+bar$)"
```

Notice that there are two different sets of options, where the inner set ignores the outer set's configuration. That'd lead to madness.

Instead, use [`source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#method-i-source) to turn the regex back into its source representation before interpolating it:

```
/^[#{regex}]+$/ # => /^[(?-mix:1234567890\[\],\ )]+$/
```

vs:

```
/^[#{regex.source}]+$/ # => /^[1234567890\[\],\ ]+$/
```

At that point the inner interpolated pattern will match the options of the outer pattern, maintaining your sanity and doing what you actually expect it to do.

At this point something like these will work:

```
test1 = [1,2,[3,4],5].to_s # => "[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]"
test1[/^[#{Regexp.escape(special)}]+$/] # => "[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]"
```

or:

```
test1[/^[#{regex.source}]+$/] # => "[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]"
```

But I'd use something more simple and be done with it:

```
test1[/^[\d\[\], ]+$/] # => "[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]"
```

Or reverse the set and make it even more simple:

```
test1[/[^\d\[\], ]/] # => nil
test2 = ["a",2,[3,4],5].to_s
test2[/[^\d\[\], ]/] # => "\""
```

Or negate it to test whether I have all the characters I want:

```
!test1[/[^\d\[\], ]/] # => true
!test2[/[^\d\[\], ]/] # => false
```

For speed and ultimate simplicity you should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/32058208/128421 though. It'll run circles around any regular expression:

```
require 'fruity'

special = "1234567890[], "
test1 = [1,2,[3,4],5].to_s # => "[1, 2, [3, 4], 5]"

compare {
  steenslag { test1.count("^0-9, []").zero? } 
  ttm { !test1[/[^\d\[\], ]/] }
  Horacio_Branciforte { test1.match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/) }
}

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> steenslag is faster than ttm by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> ttm is faster than Horacio_Branciforte by 3x ± 0.1 (results differ: true vs [1, 2, [3, 4], 5])
```

Or course, anchoring properly can make up that difference:

```
compare {
  steenslag { test1.count("^0-9, []").zero? }
  ttm { !test1[/[^\d\[\], ]/] }
  ttm1 { !test1[/^[^\d\[\], ]/] }
  ttm2 { !test1[/[^\d\[\], ]$/] }
  # stribizhev { test1.match(/\A[\[\],\p{Zs}\p{N}]+\z/) }
  Horacio_Branciforte { test1.match(/^([[:digit:]]|\]|[[:space:]]|\[|\,)*$/) }
}

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> steenslag is similar to ttm2
# >> ttm2 is similar to ttm
# >> ttm is similar to ttm1
# >> ttm1 is faster than Horacio_Branciforte by 2x ± 1.0 (results differ: true vs [1, 2, [3, 4], 5])
```

But still, `test1.count("^0-9, []").zero?` is easier to read and maintain.